# Testing any future class level changes

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

So, I have a builder class like:

```
class Person
{

private String age = "";
private String name = "";

public Person withAge(final String age)...
public Person withName(final String name)...

public Person build()...

// Now my question is due to this function
public Person copyWithSomeChange(){
Person person = new Person;
person.
    withAge(this.age+1).
    withName(this.name).
    build();
}
}
```

So, above class has a method copyWithSomeChange() which uses an existing Person object to create a new one.

Now I want to ensure if someone adds a new field to Person class, like SSN, then they doesn't forget to add that field to copyWithSomeChange() as well. I have created a unit test using reflection and did some hacks which is below, but it doesn't seem quite right.

```
@Test
public void copyWithSomeChange() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {

        Person person1 ;// some existing object

        Person person2 = person1.copyWithSomeChange();

        for (Field field : person1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                final Field temp = person2.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());

                field.setAccessible(true);
                temp.setAccessible(true);

                Assert.assertNotEquals("Mismatch in values for field " + field.getName(), field.get(person1), temp.get(person2));

           }
        }
    }
```

The way this tests work is it just makes sure that the default value of age and name are changed.

Am I taking a complete wrong approach here, I see this to be a good thing to do but how to do it the right way?

Comment: Can you share your unit test / hacks with us?

Comment: Added the unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to ensure if someone adds a new field to Person class, like
>   SSN, then they doesn't forget to add that field to
>   copyWithSomeChange() as well.

A unit test is usually not designed to "update" assertions according to code modifications done in the component under test.
While you could perform such a thing by relying on reflection.
But there still the assertion would be very loose. How do you want to write a specific assertion on a field if at the time where you write the unit test you don't know that that field exists and so the way that field should be changed in the copy ?

I think that in your case the best way to avoid error programming is using TDD or similar approach that focuses first on test and then on implementation.
In this way you are bound to detect the lack in the implementation.